# SwiftUI: How can I make an image flush with the edges of the screen in a List?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to make an image in a list flush with the edge of the screen, but if add `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())` to the Image nothing happens. 
And if I add the same code to the VStack, the formatting of the list is destroyed.

```
List {
    ForEach(users, id: \.id) { User in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Image(User.image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
            Text(User.name).font(.body)
        }
    }
} .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you don't see your images drawn edge to edge is because the `List` has a padding applied to it by default. There are two possible approaches to this:

First one. If your list of users is not very big you can place your `ForEach` inside a `ScrollView` which has no padding applied by default. Please note that it is very inefficient for large lists:

```
ScrollView {
    ForEach(users, id: \.id) { user in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Image(user.image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
            Text(user.image)
        }
    }
}
```

The second approach is a bit hacky. You can apply negative padding to your `Image` to extended it all the way to the edges:

```
List {
    ForEach(users, id: \.id { user in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Image(user.image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], -16.0)
            Text(user.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Also worth mentioning that if you declare your User type as `Identifiable`:

```
extension User: Identifiable {}
```

You will be able to declare your `ForEach` in a simpler way like this:

```
ForEach(users)
```